# Docker cannot pull any image

Tags: docker

I've installed the newest version of Docker for Windows. Everything works except docker pull. When I try to pull any image I always get information about network time out, but I know that my network is fine. Also I'm not behind any proxy. I don't know what's wrong with this. Anybody has any idea?

Comment: Can you try accessing the docker vm directly and checking if its network is up `ping google.com`?

Comment: @JustinGo I'm afraid I cannot. It's v1.12 based on Hyper-V instead boot2docker and virtualbox, I don't know if it's possible to get inside.