# Unable to pull docker images from windows when connected to office network, but works when I connect to my home network

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have installed docker on Windows, using powershell to work with Docker. I am not able to pull any images while connected to office network, If I change my network to home, it works. I am also not able to join swarm and add windows as a node.

I followed below to solve
[Docker cannot pull any image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38128717/docker-cannot-pull-any-image)
[Not able to connect docker from host when network change Docker for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45648005/not-able-to-connect-docker-from-host-when-network-change-docker-for-windows)
Found some thread on github and I have changed DNS to fixed, there are no proxies.

Please help and suggest on how could I fix this issue.

Comment: Well that's a solid indication that it's something on your company network blocking Docker. Docker uses 172.17.0.0/16 through 172.20.0.0/16 by default, so if that's your work network you'll need to change docker bridge (docker0) subnets.

Comment: Also, Docker for Windows is not meant to be joined to an existing Swarm. It can act as a single-node Swarm for local testing, but Swarm nodes in a multi-node cluster need to have many ports open between them and don't work well with the DforWin setup.

Comment: Thank you Bret Fisher for your response, I will work on your feedback.